# Redux state entry hashing

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I am trying to store a collection of data in my redux store, hashed by `id` field.

My reducer looks like:

```
// The initial state of the App
export const initialState = {
  events: {},
  loading: false,
  saving: false,
  error: false
};

const eventReducer = (state = initialState, action) =>
  produce(state, draft => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case LOAD_EVENT:
        draft.loading = true;
        draft.error = false;
        break;
      case LOAD_EVENT_SUCCESS:
        draft.loading = false;
        draft.events = {
          ...state.events,
          [action.id]: action.event
        };
        break;
      case LOAD_EVENT_ERROR:
        draft.loading = false;
        draft.error = action.error;
        break;
      case LOAD_PENDING:
        draft.loading = true;
        draft.error = false;
        break;
      case LOAD_PENDING_SUCCESS:
        draft.loading = false;
        draft.events = {
          ...state.events,
          ...action.events.map(entry => {
            return { [entry['id']]: entry };
          })
        };
        break;
      case LOAD_PENDING_ERROR:
        draft.error = action.error;
        draft.loading = false;
        break;
      case LOAD_UPCOMING:
        draft.loading = true;
        draft.error = false;
        break;
      case LOAD_UPCOMING_SUCCESS:
        draft.loading = false;
        draft.events = {
          ...state.events,
          ...action.events.map(entry => {
            return { [entry['id']]: entry };
          })
        };
        break;
      case LOAD_UPCOMING_ERROR:
        draft.error = action.error;
        draft.loading = false;
        break;
      case LOAD_PREVIOUS:
        draft.loading = true;
        draft.error = false;
        break;
      case LOAD_PREVIOUS_SUCCESS:
        draft.loading = false;
        draft.events = {
          ...state.events,
          ...action.events.map(entry => {
            return { [entry['id']]: entry };
          })
        };
        break;
      case LOAD_PREVIOUS_ERROR:
        draft.error = action.error;
        draft.loading = false;
        break;
    }
  });
```

Where `action.event` would look like `{id: 12, name: 'Test', ...}` and `action.events` would be an array like `[{id: 12, name: 'Test', ...}, {id: 15, name: 'Another test', ...}]`.

However, when I load `events` as a result of successful `LOAD_PENDING_SUCCESS` action, the state has: `{events: {0: {12, {id: 12, name: 'Test', ...}}}, {1: {15: {id: 15, name: 'Another test', ...}}}}`

I want my `events` to have the event id as the key so when I do `= {...events, ...newEvents}`, if events property of the state object has data with the same `id` as records from newEvents, events objects get replaced by the entries from newEvents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
  case LOAD_PENDING_SUCCESS:
    draft.loading = false;
    draft.events = {
      ...state.events,
      ...action.events.reduce((acc, val) => {
        return { ...acc, [val.id]: val };
      }, {})
    };
    break;
```

Or, for normalization of data, you can use normalizr library. It is super useful.